# jhipster elasticsearch шаблоны поиска

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Есть две таблицы связью многие ко многим.
Не понимаю, каким шаблоном выполнять поиск по полю с такой связью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если не ошибаюсь, должно быть так:

```
entityOneSearchRepository.search(
        QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .must(queryStringQuery(query))
            .must(matchQuery("entityTwo.id", entityTwoId))
    )
```

Comment: я имел ввиду как должен выглядеть шаблон

field:value
это один к одному.

field:value&&field:value
это искать по 2 полям

а вот как искать по конкретным филдам указывая сразу несколько значений?